# How to align the Pop up window when the Mainwindow minimizes in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, contextmenu, popupwindow

While my popup window is open, On Minimizing the mainwindow, The Popup window does not resizes and appears outside of the MainWindow.(See the image below)[image: Popup appears outside window while minimizing]

Is there any way - where we can resize the popup window and align it within the MainWindow during minimize ? Here's my code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Button Height="54" Width="50" Margin="100,0,0,0" x:Name="btnNotification"  FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="20" Content="&#x1f514;" Command="{Binding LoadNotification}" Click="btnNotification_Click"/>

<Popup Name="NotificationPopup" IsOpen="False" Closed="PopupClosed" StaysOpen="False" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnNotification}" Placement="Bottom" VerticalOffset="20">
     <Grid x:Name="PopUpGrid" Height="560" Width="360" Background="White">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
             <Button  BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Background="White" >
                 <StackPanel Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=PopUpGrid}" Orientation="Vertical">
                 <WrapPanel>
                 <Rectangle Width="20"/>
                 <TextBlock  Text="Notifications" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Light" />
                 <Button Click="btnNotification_Click" >
                 <StackPanel>
                 <TextBlock Text="&#x2715;" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="ExtraLight"/>
                 </StackPanel>
                 </Button>
                 </WrapPanel>
                 <Grid>
                 <!--Datagrid-->
                 </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public void PopupClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NotificationPopup.IsOpen = false;            
}
```

Comment: Why would the Popup resize itself when you minimize the window? Please clarify what your issue is.

Comment: @mm8 : I would want to see the popup inside the window during minimize. As of now, I see popup appearing outside when the window is minimized

Comment: Inside the window that is is minimized and thus invisible?

Comment: @mm8. Correct. So when the window is minimized, I would expect the popup to appear inside the window.

Comment: In other words, you want to hide the Popup when the window is minimized?

Comment: @mm8: No, I want to display the popup within the window, when the window is minimized

Comment: The window is not visible on the screen when it's minimized, is it?

Comment: @mm8: No, While the window is minimized, It's height and width gets reduced. That's it.